# Database app on iphone - architecture question

Tags: iphone, mysql, database, architecture, ipad

So this question is more around the design decision than anything else.Essientially, I want to build a iPhone/iPad app that will allow users to manage their database. Now there are two ways of doing this (i think).

1. Create native objective-c drivers for each database that provide a complete wrapper around creating/managing databases (tables, run query etc)

OR

2. Create a web service that does all the talking and provides a generic interface (JSON or XML) to Objective-c layer.

Which one would be better? what could be the pros and cons?

Comment: What kind of database?  SQLite? MySQL? PGSQL? something else?

Comment: let's say mysql database.. user connects with the db server and then is able to manage it remotely.. it could very well be a mssql or pgsql db server as well (later on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a self-contained app, then the first option is obviously preferable. [As far as MySQL goes, you may even find some of the Objective-C work done for you.](http://mysql-cocoa.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks Alex. I will see if I can use that in an iPhone app. 

Cheers